# How to use the object of the interface Java

Tags: java, class, interface

I have an interface like that:

```
public interface foo {
    public int addsomething (foo l) {}
    public foo dosomething() {}
}

public class abc implements foo {
    public abc(.....) {}
    public int addsomenthing (foo l) {}
    public foo dosomething() {}
}
```

How can I implement a method that in input has the object of the interface? Is it possible? I mean I have to implement addsomething with the constructor of abc(I want to do that if it's possible), not the interface object but my homework require that! And also the same thing with a method that returns the object of the interface.So the question is how can I manage the object of interface? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not very clear?

Comment: the question is very hartd to understand could u break it up a bit ?

Comment: you can't have method bodies in interfaces. Also, can you please narrow down your question to one specific one. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you wanna implement in `addsomething()`, maybe people would show you implementing that and you would understand what exactly you want.

Comment: How can I use the object of the interface? I mean if in the interface there were public int addsomething(abc l){}  and public abc dosomething() {} for example it was easy to implement that methods. I don't know how to implement methods with the object of the interface because I have to return or use the costructor of abc.

Comment: I think what you want to do is have the abc class listen to some action in another class.  You will want to pass the object of the abc class to the class that you will listen to, perhaps to the constructor of the other class and then you can use the object of abc which implemented foo to call method addsomenthing(foo data).  If that's what you want to do, let me know and i will give you an example in the answer below.

Comment: What is an "object of the interface"?

Comment: The whole point of this is that you can have  a variable whose type is `Foo`, which refers to an object whose class is `Abc`.  So `Foo something = new Abc();`.

Comment: foo isn't the object of the interface?

Comment: @HKing please read the Java tutorial about interfaces. And try learning the correct terminology. "the object of the interface" doesn't mean anything to us.

Comment: There are methods of the interface that use Foo,I implement that interface with a class. Now I have to implement that methods,how can I do that if it require to return Foo or in input has Foo?

Comment: Input Foo **doesnt** mean that it can **only** take in a Foo. It means that it can take in a Foo **or** a child of Foo (declared by putting extends/implements Foo in the class/interface declaration). Abc implements Foo, thus it is a valid input for a function like "void test(Foo foo)"

Comment: Yes now I understand,but now there is another problem. If I define the constructor of abc with some variable,I can't acces it with Foo

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use Anonymous classes.

EDIT:
After reading your comment on your question, I think this will instead be what you want:

```
interface Foo
{
    public int addsomething(Foo l);

    public Foo dosomething();
}

class Abc implements Foo
{
    @Override
    public int addsomething(Foo l)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Foo dosomething()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Abc();
        Abc abc = new Abc();
        test(foo);
        test(abc);
    }

    private static void test(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.dosomething();
    }
}
```

Here you can see that a function can take interfaces as parameters and instances of classes that implement that interface can be given as input to the function calls.

Comment: This design is used very often with listeners or events, or anything like that. That is why anyone would want to do that. Why the OP wants to do that is a different question that I cannot answer... nor if this is what he wanted to have, but this is what I think he wants.

Comment: I changed the answer after reading the comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this:

```
public interface foo {
    public int addsomething (foo l) {}
    public foo dosomething() {}
}

public class abc implements foo {
    public abc(.....) {}
    public int addsomething (foo l) {
    //do something with foo object after class "MyOtherClass" has invoked
    addsomething method.
    }
    public foo dosomething() {}

   MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(abc abcObject);
}

//my other class
public class MyOtherClass{
 abc abcObject;

 //my constructor
 public MyOtherClass(abc abcObject){
 this.abcObject=abcObject;
 }
 //call method from class implementing interface
 abcObject.addsomething(FooObject);
}
```